# How to find sum of these values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, sum-of-digits

I'm trying to create a script for analysing my datas. Here is my problem. Let's say I have an excel file like that.

```
Code Value
A1    20
B1    30
A1    15
C1    20
B1    20
```

I need Pandas to do this file like this. And write an excel file. I got an excel file like this.

```
A1 35
B1 50
C1 20
```

Code pretty much like this.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

Missing Part Here

x.to_excel(r'filename.xlsx', index = True, header=True)
```

And I need missing part. Thanks a lot for your solutions already.

Trying to automate my data analysis. Expect adding part of my script.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is not a free coding service, a common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
>>> df
  Code  Value
0   A1     20
1   B1     30
2   A1     15
3   C1     20
4   B1     20

>>> df.groupby('Code', as_index=False)['Value'].sum()
  Code  Value
0   A1     35
1   B1     50
2   C1     20
```

Please take the time to read [10 minutes to Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html)